# Pascal: Calling an empty method on a class segfaults

Tags: pascal, freepascal, delphi

I've got a very stark class.

```
unit StuffClass;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

type
  TStuffClass = class
    public
      procedure Update;
  end;

implementation

procedure TStuffClass.Update;
begin

end;

end.
```

Creating an instance of it, and calling its `Update` procedure causes the program to SIGSEGV..

What the..? It's doing absolutely nothing.

I am using the Freepascal (& Lazarus) 32 bit version.

Why does it do this?

EDIT: Here is the calling bit:

```
//Creating it
constructor TEngine.Create(TV: pSDL_Surface);
begin
  Self.TV := TV;
  Self.StuffClass.Create;
end;

function TEngine.Update: Boolean;
begin
  WriteLN('Test');
  SDL_PumpEvents;

  Self.StuffClass.Update; //Crashes here.
  Update := True;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating it wrong.

You need to store the returned object instance to a variable, and then use that variable (reference) instead:

```
constructor TEngine.Create(TV: pSDL_Surface);
begin
  Self.TV := TV;
  Self.StuffClass := TStuffClass.Create;
end;
```

Now the rest of your code can use it:

```
procedure TEngine.SomeOtherProcedure;
begin
  Self.StuffClass.Update;
end;
```

Comment: Actually, I'm doing that. The `StuffClass` is a private member of another class called `Engine`.

Comment: Then don't make us try and guess what you're doing wrong. Post the actual code that exhibits the problem behavior. The class definition without showing how you're using it that causes the error is meaningless.

Comment: Just showed I was right with my guess. :-) I edited my answer to show using your actual code. Thanks for the edit. :-)

Comment: Hey, thanks. What a stupid mistake on my part. (You're also the guy who answered my Pascal dumb questions earlier, so thanks for that as well!)